# Importing Spark Source Code to Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, apache-spark

I want to modify an algorithm from the Spark Source Code. In Eclipse Luna, I tried to import the source codes by File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace but after that, the src folder does not have any file. So how should I go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark project consist of  multiple modules

[pom.xml](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/pom.xml)

```
  <modules>
     <module>common/sketch</module>
     <module>common/network-common</module>
     <module>common/network-shuffle</module>
     <module>common/unsafe</module>
     <module>common/tags</module>
     <module>core</module>
     <module>graphx</module>
     <module>mllib</module>
     <module>tools</module>
     <module>streaming</module>
     <module>sql/catalyst</module>
     <module>sql/core</module>
     <module>sql/hive</module>
     <module>external/docker-integration-tests</module>
     <module>assembly</module>
     <module>examples</module>
     <module>repl</module>
     <module>launcher</module>
     <module>external/kafka</module>
     <module>external/kafka-assembly</module>
   </modules>
```

If you want to import complete Spark project try this:

> File -> Import -> Select -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects -> (Select the root directory of Spark project)

Note: Make sure you have eclipse-maven-plugin already installed.

Comment: thanks! By the way, my objective really is just to edit a code inside spark-mllib. Can I just compile this code instead of the whole Spark project?

Comment: Since source code of all modules are within the root directory so they will also imported as maven-project. You only have to change the desire code in mllib module and rebuild the complete project or just mllib module.

Answer (score 0):

cd to the home directory of your spark source code.
run :

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

this will help you to convert your spark project to a eclipse-maven project.

then:

```
File -> Import -> Select -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects -> (Select the root directory of Spark project)
```